# Missing ZendExtensionManager.so

Tags: php, zend-framework

What php extension should I install to get the missing **ZendExtensionManager.so** file?

```
$ php --version
Failed loading /usr/local/zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so, 9): image not found
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 27 2016 11:19:10)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

$ php --ini
Failed loading /usr/local/zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so, 9): image not found
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Users/MyGGaN/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.16/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /Users/MyGGaN/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.16/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /Users/MyGGaN/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.16/var/db
Additional .ini files parsed:      /Users/MyGGaN/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.16/var/db/intl.ini,
/Users/MyGGaN/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.16/var/db/zip.ini
```

One section from my **php.ini**:

```
[zend]
zend_extension=/usr/local/zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so
zend.install_dir=/usr/local/zend
; The dir all configuration files are stored in.
zend.conf_dir=/usr/local/zend/etc
zend.ini_scandir=conf.d
```

I don't think it's a configuration issue, I just simply don't have that file. But I'm not able to figure out how to get hold of it.

Thanks!

Comment: do you really need it, you can disabled it instead ?

Comment: Interesting solution, I'll try :)